# Primefaces ошибка NullPointerExceptio

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <p:fileUpload  value="#{someBean.uploadedFile}" mode="simple" />
         <p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{someBean.upload}" ajax="false"/>
     </h:form>
</html>
```

Код

```
package web;

import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;


import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile; // +getter+setter

    public void upload() {
        String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
        String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Example.pdf");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];

            inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // записываем из буфера в файл
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при добавлении PDFа на задеплоином приложении получаю NullPointerException.Спасибо.

Comment: а файл точно приходит в upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код рабочий, загрузка и сохранение файла проходит без ошибок. Скорее всего, проблема с настройками веб-приложения. Проверьте, чтобы при старте сервера и приложения в логах не было ошибок, например `ClassNotFoundException`.
Проверьте конфигурацию в `web.xml`, прилагаю вариант, на котором тестирование прошло успешно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Если ошибка повторится, добавьте лог стектрейса в вопрос.